Union of the support of Borel probability measures is compact
Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $M(X)$ the set of all Borel probability measures on $X$. It is know that $M(X)$ is a convex compact metric space endowed with the weak-* topology i.e. $\left(\mu_n\right)_n \subseteq M(X)$ converges to $\mu \in M(X)$ iff for all continuous function $f \in C(X)$ $\int_X f d \mu_n \rightarrow \int_X f d \mu$. With this definition the linear functions $\mu \rightarrow \int_X f d \mu$ are continuous and hence $\mathcal{B}(M(X))$-measurable.
Let $Y$ be a compact subset of $X$.
Let $H:=\bigcup_{\mu \in M(Y)}\text{supp}\mu.$ Is it true that $H$ is a compact set?

We have $H\subseteq Y$ as the measures are on $Y$. However, we also have $Y\subseteq H$ as we have Dirac deltas supported on singeltons of $Y$. Thus, $H=Y$ is compact. Is this really the question you had in mind?

As $Y$ is compact, we get for $\mu \in M(Y)$ that $\mathrm{supp}(\mu)\subseteq Y$ (even if we think of the support on $X$). Thus, $H\subseteq Y$.
On the other hand, we have that all singeltons in $Y$ are measurable (as $Y$ is a metric space). We can consider the Dirac delta measure $\delta_y$ on $y\in Y$. We know $\mathrm{supp}(\delta_y)=\{y\}$ and $\delta_y\in M(Y)$. Hence, $y\in H$ for all $y\in Y$ and therefore $Y\subseteq H$.
In total, we get $H=Y$ is compact.
